# Como puedo simular una base de datos para poder realiza una prueba unitaria a mi metodo actualizar?

Tags: java, pruebas-unitarias, mockito

Tengo una clase en java llamada **ModeloDatos.java** la cual cuenta con varios metodos, uno de ellos es el siguiente:

```
public void actualizarJugador(String nombre) {
    try {
        set = con.createStatement();
        set.executeUpdate("UPDATE Jugadores SET votos=votos+1 WHERE nombre " + " LIKE '%" + nombre + "%'");
        rs.close();
        set.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // No modifica la tabla
        System.out.println("No modifica la tabla");
        System.out.println("El error es: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Metodo que actualiza la cantidada de votos de una persona, sumandole 1 al voto actual de la base de datos.
Entonces, me gustaria saber de que forma puedo hacer pruebas unitarias usando **mockito** o no, para **simular una base de datos** y poder comprobar que se está actualizando correctamente +1 el voto de la persona.

Answer (score 1):

Generalmente no necesitas probar la capa de base de datos porque usas algun framework de persistencia, pero si no es el caso, realmente necesitas verificar que se hayan realizado operaciones transaccionales o su respectiva canelacion, o estas en un sistema que se conecta directamente a varias bases de datos, te recomiendo usar [dbunit](/questions/tagged/dbunit).

Para agregar la libreria si usas maven basta con agregar la dependencia

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
  <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Para ello necesitaras primero un xml con tus datos, por ejemplo

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <jugadores id="1" nombre="Usuario 1" votos="1"/>
  <jugadores id="2" nombre="Usuario 2" votos="5"/>
</dataset>
```

donde el nombre de tu tabla seria `jugadores` y tendria las columnas, `id`, `nombre` y votos.

normalmente se integra con alguna base de datos, he visto por conveninecia algunas bases de datos en memoria como [h2](/questions/tagged/h2) para realizar los cambios alli y poderlos verificar rapidamente.

Te dejo una liga de un tutorial por si gustas ahondar un poco mas: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dbunit

Answer (score 0):

para hacer el test hay dos opciones.

La primera sería que después de actualizar al jugador, en el método del test, hagas una consulta a la base de datos y con un assertEquals o assertSame compruebas que el dato que te trae la consulta es el mismo al que tu esperas.

La segunda opción es la más recomendable ya que no dependes de estar conectado a la base de datos. Es con test containers. En el momento del test te crea la base de datos y te hace los inserts que tu le pongas. Entonces tu en el test actualizas al jugador y haces la consulta a la bbdd que te ha mockeado el test container.

[test container doc](https://www.testcontainers.org)